# GDB Can't Display Boost uBLAS Matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix, gdb, boost-ublas

I have a successfully compiled program using Boost's implementation of uBLAS matricies. Alas, debugging with gdb is proving problematic as I could find no way to see the contents of my matrices while debugging. When I try to see an element of a matrix V (which does exist and is full of data), I get:

```
(gdb) print V(1,1)
Invalid data type for function to be called.
```

Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because GDB doesn't support calling the overloaded `operator()`. It's trying to just call `V` as a function, and it's not a function. You can write a freestanding function that you pass the matrix to and calls the operator:

```
int get_element(matrix const &m,int i,int j) {
    return m(i,j);
}

(gdb) p get_element(V,1,1)
(int) $0 = 43.1
```

and GDB should be able to call that

You can also try to manually examine the representation of `V` in order to manually pull out the value you want. That's probably going to be hard with types that use a lot of templates or meta-programming though.

If you happen to be working on a platform that is supported by LLDB, it supports calling operator overloads.

```
struct foo {
    int operator()(int i,int j) {
        return 10;
    }
};

(lldb) p f(1,1)
(int) $0 = 10
```

Comment: That's an unfortunate limitation for `gdb`, but a reasonable workaround. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

One can call

```
V.operator()(1,1)
```

in gdb

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread when looking for a solution for this problem. The proposed solution works fine. However, you could also use the `at_element` method of ublas matrices.